# How to extract first 10 characters in a string, then 2-11, then 3-12 and so on in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have the following string that I want to split into multiple strings traversing position by position:
`GAATAAATGAATAAATGGATAATGAACAAATAAATAAATGGTTATAAAGATGGTAGGATTTCAGCTAGACTTTTAAGGATTGACCTTTTATCAAGAAAATG`

I would like to extract first 10 characters:
`GAATAAATGA`
Then 2-11
`AATAAATGAA`
Then 3-12
`ATAAATGAAT`

and so on until I have the last 10 characters
`CAAGAAAATG`

I know the way to extract first few characters is `string.[0:9]`. How do I do this in a recurring fashion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to print the substring every time -

```
str='GAATAAATGAATAAATGGATAATGAACAAATAAATAAATGGTTATAAAGATGGTAGGATTTCAGCTAGACTTTTAAGGATTGACCTTTTATCAAGAAAATG'
length = 10
for i in range(0, len(str)-length):
    print (i, i+length, str[i:i+length])
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask one more output? Can you also print the position next to the actual string i.e:     



`1_10   GAATAAATGA`
`2_11   AATAAATGAA`

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic approach:

```
tokens = [mystring[index:index + 10] for index in range (len(mystring) - 10 + 1) ]
```

Comment: This will result mystring[0:10], mystring[10:20], and so on but s\he also ask for mystring[1:11]